# TooManyClauses error with version 1.7 Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-1.7.5

I use Elasticsearch with version 1.7 (I know it is very old). I got TooManyClauses error and I wanted to increase the default value of max_clause_count. (default 1024)

Unfortunately, I couldn't set the configuration for elasticsearch. I tried these 2 settings:

```
1- "indices.query.bool.max_clause_count=2048"
2- "index.query.bool.max_clause_count=2048"
```

Do you have any ideas? How can I change the default value for max_clause_count?

Comment: The configuration that you tried should work (I hope you are not using the double quotes) after you add them in elasticsearch.yml file. Post that, Please restart the nodes (any change in the config file needs a restart).

Comment: I am using a docker image and adding this configuration as environment variables. So, I don't have the elasticsearch.yml due to the docker image. I just did a restart but it didn't work for me. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: `environment:`
      `indices.query.bool.max_clause_count: 2048`

This worked for me. Are you adding the same in your docker-compose.yml ?

Comment: I am setting the environments in container definition file for ECS. I am deploying elastic search to an AWS cluster. I am defining the parameters like here. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_environment 

Unfortunately it's still not working.

Comment: When I check the settings with that pah `/_cluster/settings/?include_defaults`, I still see 1024 which is the default value.